# Retrying when sending request with WebClient "blocks" the other subscribers

Tags: java, spring-webflux, project-reactor

I opened the issue at Reactor-core github, but maybe it's not their responsibilty so no one helped me there.

https://github.com/reactor/reactor-core/issues/1551
Introduction of the general flow:

1. When a request is got from controller, a Flux is created and publish series of messages.
2. Multiple subscribers subscribe to that Flux.
3. onNext, each subscriber sends Api Request to specific Server.
4. The requests, (actually to the response) an intermediate operation of retrying is added.

```java
Scheduler requestsScheduler = Schedulers.single();
Scheduler retryingScheduler = Schedulers.newSingle("retrying_thread");

protected void hookOnNext(Message message) {
    getWebClient()
        .buildRequest(message)
        .publishOn(requestsScheduler)
        .retryWhen(c -> retryByPolicy(c))
        .publishOn(requestsScheduler )
        .subscribe(new ResponseSubscriber(this)); 
}

private Flux<Long> retryByPolicy(Flux<Throwable> companionErrors) {
    int firstRetryIndex = 1;
    return companionErrors.publishOn(retryingScheduler)
        .zipWith(Flux.range(firstRetryIndex,this.maxRetries),(err, retryIndex) -> {
            if (retryIndex >= maxRetries )
                throw Exceptions.propagate(new ReachedMaxRetriesException());
            else
                return retryIndex;
        })
        .flatMap(retryIndex -> Mono.delay(this.retryDelay(retryIndex), retryingScheduler))
        .publishOn(requestsScheduler );
}
```

4. To that request , a "ResponseSubscriber" handles the incoming response and call the "MessageSubscriber".subscription.request(1).

#### Expected behavior

All the retrying handling is asynchronous and parallel to the others MessageSubscriber handling

#### Actual behavior

On retrying, all others MessageSubscriber are waiting to the complete response handling of specific MessageSubscriber that is on "retrying".

Example 1 - only when MessageSubscriberB is failed to send the request, MessageSubscriberA starts sending

```
03-03 14:25:56   [reactor-http-nio-3]   INFO   ControlelrRequest "1551615956502" changed its status from 'PENDING' to 'IN_PROGRESS'
03-03 14:25:56   [reactor-http-nio-3]   INFO   messageSubscriberA  Request: POST http://localhost:8080/REST/Command/1551615956412 of Message #1
03-03 14:25:56   [reactor-http-nio-3]   INFO   messageSubscriberB Request: POST http://172.29.50.248:8080/REST/Command/1551615956412 of Message #1
03-03 14:25:56   [single-1]   INFO   responseSubscriberA Handling Web response of Message #1 
03-03 14:25:57   [retrying_thread-2]   WARN   In retrying policy of messageSubscriberB : trying to send the Message #1 to 'SerberB' had failed - trying #1
03-03 14:26:18   [retrying_thread-2]    WARN   In retrying policy of messageSubscriberB : trying to send the Message #1 to 'SerberB' had failed - trying #2
03-03 14:26:39   [retrying_thread-2]     WARN   In retrying policy of messageSubscriberB : trying to send the Message #1 to 'SerberB' had failed - trying #3
03-03 14:26:39   [single-1]  ERROR   Failed to send requests (Message #1) to the server 'ServerB'. got failed after reached max retries code
03-03 14:26:39   [single-1]   INFO  messageSubscriberA  Request: POST http://localhost:8080/REST/Command/1551615956412 of Message #2
03-03 14:26:40   [single-1]   INFO   responseSubscriberA Handling Web response of Message #228 
03-03 14:26:40   [single-1]   INFO  messageSubscriberA  Request: POST http://localhost:8080/REST/Command/1551615956412 of Message #3
03-03 14:26:40   [single-1]   INFO   responseSubscriberA Handling Web response of Message #3
03-03 14:26:40   [single-1]   INFO  messageSubscriberA  Request: POST http://localhost:8080/REST/Command/1551615956412 of Message #4
03-03 14:26:41   [single-1]   INFO   responseSubscriberA Handling Web response of Message #4
03-03 14:26:41   [single-1]   WARN   ControlelrRequest "1551615956502" changed its status from 'IN_PROGRESS' to 'DONE' with failures.
```

Reactor Core version
reactor-core.3.2.3.RELEASE

JVM version (e.g. java -version)
java version "11.0.1" 2018-10-16 LTS
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment 18.9 (build 11.0.1+13-LTS)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM 18.9 (build 11.0.1+13-LTS, mixed mode)

Comment: I edited to be more clearly.